# I can't stream direct mp4 file (error 400, bad requests), but i can download the same file with python requests with proper header?

Tags: python, stream, python-requests

Ok, this is an example of direct link:

```
"http://xyuuz.net/vids/test.bluray.x264.zzz___5704c6b167976.mp4"
```

I can download the same file with python requests and only with proper header:

```
import requests
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Referer': 'http://somereffer.com/watch/35vcghddfgde56'}

response = requests.get('http://xyuuz.net/vids/test.bluray.x264.zzz___5704c6b167976.mp4', headers=headers)
```

In response.headers i see 'Content-Type=video/mp4'

A whole headers is here, if this mean something:

```
'Content-Length': '504838710', 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, HEAD, OPTIONS', 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': 'Server,range,Content-Length,Content-Range', 'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes', 'Expires': 'Sat, 25 Jul 2020 02:57:08 GMT', 'Server': 'nginx/1.10.2', 'Last-Modified': 'Wed, 06 Apr 2016 08:35:22 GMT', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'ETag': '"5704ca4a-1e173a36"', 'Cache-Control': 'max-age=8640000', 'Date': 'Thu, 16 Apr 2020 02:57:08 GMT', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*', 'Content-Type': 'video/mp4'
```

I don't want to download. I want to stream the same url in some media player.

Is it possible to pass bad requests from server?

Comment: _I don't want to download._ What do you mean? What do you want to do with the file, then?

Comment: Yeah i know i made a mess, because English is not my natural language, sorry.

The goal is: stream the same url in some media player. but i can't, mp4 url is 'dead' because of "Bad requests" which server returns.

Comment: _Yeah i know i made a mess, because English is not my natural language, sorry._ Eh, don't worry about it. _mp4 url is 'dead' because of "Bad requests" which server returns._ So the media player can't get the file, while your program using requests can?

Comment: Yes! Media player (MPC, VLC...) gives me "error".

I think there is some trick on server which does not allow stream. I can get file (download), but only with header, without problem.

Comment: _I can get file (download), but only with header, without problem._ Ah wait, without the User-Agent the Python script can't access the file either? I just realized I'm not sure what you're trying to do with this file.

Comment: Yes, you are right.
 Without user-agent python can't acces file. Response is "400 - Bad requests".

Comment: Alright, that makes sense. What are you trying to do here? Is this part of a larger Python program?

Comment: I am scraping a web site. And trying to send mp4 stream to local player.

Comment: That shouldn't be an issue then, no? Can't you pass the mp4 to the player through Python? How are you interacting with the player?

Comment: I have some my own plyer. It's simple. I just send mp4 link to player. But this not a problem. I need to find a way to send link with user-agent to player, somehow.

Comment: You wrote it yourself? Is it part of the same program, how is it running? That might complicate things a bit. Either way, wouldn't using requests to get mp4 and then passing it to the player work?